# Find date difference in Oracle SQL based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

table1

```
tran_id    user_id    start_date    end_date
1          100        01-06-2018    18-06-2018
2          100        14-06-2018    14-06-2018
4          100        19-07-2018    19-07-2018
7          101        05-01-2018    06-01-2018
9          101        08-01-2018    08-01-2018
3          101        03-01-2018    03-01-2018
```

DEMO - [Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1ba586c41e9788e2f0916d3ecaa4b183)

Here is the logic:

I need to find the day difference between two `trans_id` for a member sorted by start_date where there is no overlapping start_date and end_date.

We need to check the max end_date for a user processing one record at a time.

The logic would be:

For a member:

- sort all records by `user_id` and `start_date`
- `trans_id` = 1, `end_date` = 18-06-2018
  , set `max_end_date` = 18-06-2018
- `trans_id` = 2, `end_date` = 14-06-2018, `end_date` < `max_end_date`, move forward
- `trans_id` = 3, `end_date` = 19-07-2018, `end_date` > `max_end_date`, add a record in output where

  - `transidfrom` = 1 (as this is the record with `max_end_date`)
  - `transidto` = 4 (as this is the record where `end_date` > `max_end_date`)
  - `transidfrom_end_date` = 18-06-2018, pick the `end_date` of `trans_id` of `transidfrom`
  - `transidto_start_date` = 19-07-2018, pick the `start_date` of `trans_id` of `transidto`
  - `datediff` = `transidto_start_date` - `transidfrom_end_date`

The output would be as follows:

table2

```
my_id    transidfrom    transidto    transidfrom_end_date    transidto_start_date   datediff
1        1              4            18-06-2018              19-07-2018             31
2        3              7            03-01-2018              05-01-2018             2
3        7              9            06-01-2018              08-01-2018             2
```

Is there a way to do this in Oracle SQL in 1 query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your requirement correctly, then maybe this will do it:

```
FSITJA@db01 2019-07-08 12:08:59> with table1(tran_id, user_id, start_date, end_date) as (
  2      select 1, 100, date '2018-06-01', date '2018-06-18' from dual union all
  3      select 2, 100, date '2018-06-14', date '2018-06-14' from dual union all
  4      select 4, 100, date '2018-07-19', date '2018-07-19' from dual union all
  5      select 7, 101, date '2018-01-05', date '2018-01-06' from dual union all
  6      select 9, 101, date '2018-01-08', date '2018-01-08' from dual union all
  7      select 3, 101, date '2018-01-03', date '2018-01-03' from dual )
  8  select rownum        as my_id,
  9         tran_id       as transidfrom,
 10         next_tran_id  as transidto,
 11         end_date      as transidfrom_end_date,
 12         next_end_date as transidto_start_date,
 13         datediff
 14    from (select tran_id,
 15                 user_id,
 16                 start_date,
 17                 end_date,
 18                 lead(tran_id) over (partition by user_id order by end_date) next_tran_id,
 19                 lead(start_date) over (partition by user_id order by end_date) next_end_date,
 20                 lead(start_date) over (partition by user_id order by end_date) - end_date datediff
 21            from table1)
 22   where datediff > 0;

     MY_ID TRANSIDFROM  TRANSIDTO TRANSIDFROM_END_DAT TRANSIDTO_START_DAT   DATEDIFF
---------- ----------- ---------- ------------------- ------------------- ----------
         1           1          4 2018-06-18 00:00:00 2018-07-19 00:00:00         31
         2           3          7 2018-01-03 00:00:00 2018-01-05 00:00:00          2
         3           7          9 2018-01-06 00:00:00 2018-01-08 00:00:00          2

3 rows selected.
```

[SQL Fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=06ccbafa996858ad9e8659d31126f891)